# What are some recommended user signup / logged-in user MVC/OData and public-facing API data access strategies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, odata

We're building a new application that will have a user signup and logged-in user area.  Authenticated users will have access to our API.

I wanted to separate the user signup OData endpoint from the logged in/API-access OData endpoints.

For new-user signups, a separate in-network API works.  However, public-facing, I'd like to know some proven architectural strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that you could use FormsAuthentication to lock down access based on users and/or roles in your MVC application. OAuth could be used in conjunction to handoff the identifying info to your authentication/authorization routines.

Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192996.aspx) on using OData and FormsAuthentication.

Comment: Makes sense.  What about API access?  I've built strategies that use a session-based auth, but want to get away from this.  I want to use an OData endpoint and looking for suggestions.  The article suggests  forms auth, but for API access?  Sending in an valid user's GUID as part of the request may work, but interested in hearing about some caveats to this method.

Comment: I hate to continue to add article pointers but this one describes turning your web api into an an OData provider. This could still use the authentication mechanism as a separate piece. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx